# How can I convert the string values inside a MySQL JSON array to upper case?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table that contains a JSON column, and in it a JSON array:

```
mysql> SELECT profile->'$.countriesVisited' from users;
+-------------------------------+
| profile->'$.countriesVisited' |
+-------------------------------+
| ["us", "il"]                  |
| ["co", "ph"]                  |
+-------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to convert the values inside the array into upper case. (I am assuming this answer would also assist lower case, string replacements.. etc.)

I've been trying to use UPPER, JSON_ARRAY, JSON_QUOTE, JSON_UNQUOTE, etc - at best I end up with a string representation of what I want.

How can I do this? I'm running MySQL 5.7.19.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [JSON casting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-converting-between-types). Try the following:

```
UPDATE users 
SET profile = JSON_SET(
  profile, 
  '$.countriesVisited', 
  CAST(
    UPPER(profile->'$.countriesVisited') 
    AS JSON
  )
);
```